# How to replace file string via fabric at remote server?

Tags: python, file-io, fabric

I want to use `fabric` to replace remote server file string. Code below.

```
def readsn():

    with open(hn) as f:
        while True:
            line=f.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            desthost = line.strip().lstrip().rstrip()
            env.host_string = desthost
            run('cp %s %s' %(path,path+time.strftime(r'%Y%m%d%H%M%S', time.localtime())))
            run(change_conf(path, old, new))

def change_conf(path,old,new):
    f = fileinput.input(path,backup='.bak',inplace=True)
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        match = re.match(r,line)
        if match:
            print line.replace(old, new)
        print line
    f.close()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "change_conf_batch.py", line 45, in <module>
    readsn()
  File "change_conf_batch.py", line 32, in readsn
    run(change_conf(path, old, new))
  File "/root/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.10/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 677, in host_prompting_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.10/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 1088, in run
    shell_escape=shell_escape, capture_buffer_size=capture_buffer_size,
  File "/root/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.10/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 914, in _run_command
    _prefix_env_vars(_prefix_commands(command, 'remote')),
  File "/root/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.10/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 670, in _prefix_commands
    return prefix + command
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Comment: always show full error message (traceback) in question. There are other usefull information - like line which makes problem.

Comment: if remote server uses Linux then you can use Linux commands in fabric - ie. `sed` (**S**tream **ED**itor) - `example: sed "s/old_text/new_text/g" old_file >new_file`

Comment: run(change_conf(path, old, new)) shows flowing full error

Comment: show full error message in question - not part of message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`run()` expects string with command. It can run only programs/scripts which are on remote server - it can't run your function.

BTW: now Python first executes your function which returns `None` and then `run()` use this result as command to execute on server.

If you have Linux on remote server then you could use `sed` command. ie.

```
run('sed "s/old_text/new_text/g" old_file > new_file')
```

Or you have to copy your script on remote server and then run it

---

You can also download file from server ([get()](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.12/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.get)), change it locally (using your function) and send back on server ([put()](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.12/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put))

Comment: thanks for your time.now how can I run my function at remote server?sorry newie here

Comment: First method: send script with your function on server (`put()`) and execute this script on server using `run()` (uploaded script doesn't need `run()`). Second: download edited file from server `get()`, use your function on this file locally, send back on server `put()`